# Timing between 2 GPIO inputs

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python

I have 2 buttons hooked up to my Raspberry Pi3.

I am trying to find out the time between each button press and if the second button even gets pressed at all.

For Example:
Button#1 is pressed, then a counter of 15 seconds starts and if Button#2 is NOT pressed within that time frame then the code does something. If button#2 IS pressed within the time frame then the elapsed time would be printed and counter reset waiting for Button#1 again.

I am able to get the time elapsed when the Button#2 gets pressed but I need to account for Button#2 not getting pressed within the time frame.

Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
gpio.setup(17, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)


while True:
    input_value_4 = gpio.input(4)
    input_value_17 = gpio.input(17)

if input_value_4 == 1:
    print("Ball Detected IN")
    start = time.time()

if input_value_17 == 1:
    print("Ball Detected OUT")
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: add an if statement to the end of your while loop and compare the diff between start time and now against your 15 second time out.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(4, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
gpio.setup(17, gpio.IN, pull_up_down=gpio.PUD_DOWN)
b1pressed = False  # has button 1 been pressed?
start = 0
end = 0


while True:
    input_value_4 = gpio.input(4)
    input_value_17 = gpio.input(17)

    if input_value_4 == 1:
        print("Ball Detected IN")
        b1pressed = True # so it knows button 1 has been pressed.
        start = time.time()

    if input_value_17 == 1:
        print("Ball Detected OUT")
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
        b1pressed = False # sets b1pressed false to reset the program.

    if end - start > 15 and b1pressed == True: 
        # only does this if b1 has been pressed:
        print("Button 2 not pressed")
        b1pressed = False # then sets b1pressed to false to reset again.
        #do something

    time.sleep(0.1)
```